# Can't change router component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

I have a .vue file with the following

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<h2>Create your MIA</h2>
<p><img src="../../static/intro.gif"/></p>
<p><a v-on:click="go()" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">Enter</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    go: function () {
      console.log(this.$router.go)
      this.$router.go({ path: '/app' })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and in a main index.html file I have

```
<main class="container center">
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="section">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </main>
```

and in my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Resource from 'vue-resource'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import App from './components/app'
import Intro from './components/intro'

Vue.use(Resource)
Vue.use(Router)

const route = new Router({hashbang: false,
    history: true,
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    mode: 'html5'})

// Pointing routes to the components they should use
route.map({
  '/': {
    component: Intro,
    subRoutes: {
      'app': {
        component: App
      }
    }
  },
  '/app': {
    component: App
  }
})

// Any invalid route will redirect to home
route.redirect({
  '*': '/app'
})

route.start(Intro, '#section')
```

When the stuff is compiled I am able to get the  `Intro` component but click on the button only changes the hash but not the component....

Based on the documentation the only thing that I'm doing different is that I am changing the route programmatically.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why aren't you doing `<a v-link="{ path: '/app' }">`? And why do you have two `/app` routes?

Comment: because v-link wasn't working and not sure if the route was a sub route since i'm triggering the route from WITHIN a component @ceejayoz

Comment: You're triggering the link within a component, but you're using `path` and an absolute path (`/app`) so that's entirely irrelevant. Figure out why `v-link` doesn't work instead of doing a weird kludge. I'd start with the fact that you've got two `/app` routes defined and work from there.

Comment: @ceejayoz been doing for a while now but no luck. apparently router-view doesn't work unless its inside a component...weird because it should still work...not so?

Comment: is it that i have to re-instanciate a new router object in order to replace the currently loaded component

Comment: It works fine outside a component (that's how [the "basic usage" page](http://router.vuejs.org/en/basic.html) on vue-router's documentation suggests, even).  There's no need to re-instantiate the router. Start with the basic example at http://router.vuejs.org/en/basic.html and work from there.